# Cannot "stringify" geoJSON data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, geojson, stringify

Using Leaflet JavaScript I am trying to pull data directly from GeoServer using an Ajax link. In order to put it nicely in a DataTables table, I need to JSON.stringify it per DataTables instructions. I get a "Circular structure". Is there any other way to do this?

Here is my code:

Get Selected Features from GeoServer via Ajax

```
function handleJson(data) {

  selectedFeature = L.geoJson(data, {

    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {

    },
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {

        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius: 5,
            color: '#3006e8',
            weight: 5,
            opacity: 100,
            fillOpacity: 100
        });
    }
  });
  selectedFeature.addTo(drawnItems);
```

Now here is where I would idealy use JSON.stringify to achieve these results provide by a very helpful person over at datatables.net....

http://live.datatables.net/sokitihe/3/edit

I think var selectedFeature would be the data to JSON.stringify correct? I have tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: JSON can't serialize custom classes, functions, etc. The JSON format only supports base value types (int, bool, string, array, object literal)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is there any way to parse geoJSON data directly from an Ajax link? Or somehow assign it to a var and then parse that? I just need to get the GeoJSON data from Ajax and use JSON.parse and assign it to the variable "data" then use that data to build columns for Datatables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the GeoJSON LayerGroup directly into a FeatureCollection using:

```
selectedGeoJSON = selectedFeature.toGeoJSON();
```

Then you can do what you want with it, stringify it if you wish.

```
JSON.stringify(selectedGeoJSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ethan McCoy 's answer seems resolved my problem. My code like the following:

```
const leaflet = require('leaflet')
leaflet.then(L => {
    // response is geojson
    const data=L.geoJson(response).toGeoJSON()
    return JSON.stringify(data)
})
```